# How to get a razor variable (ASP .NET) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to send a picture to the server and then to copy the link into my dataBase. I'm using the code `razor` & `Html`  from `Microsoft doc`:

```
@{  WebImage photo = null;
    var newFileName = "";
    var imagePath = "";
    var myPath = "DefaultPath";

    if(IsPost){
        photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
        if(photo != null){
            newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" +
                Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
            imagePath = @"images/" + newFileName;

            photo.Save(@"~/" + imagePath);
            myPath= "/" + imagePath;
        }
    }
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Upload Image </legend>
      <label for="Image">Image</label>
      <input type="file" name="Image" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <h1>Uploaded Image</h1>
    @if(imagePath != ""){
    <div class="result">
        <img src="@myPath" alt="image" />
    </div>

    <div id="toJavaScript">@myPath</div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

This code is working well: after clicking, the image is shown. But my goal is to get the variable `@myPath` into `JavaScript`.

The last div contains `@myPath` and it is correctly shown after upload clicking (because of refreshing). But in JavaScript, when I'm doing:

```
var ImageRootText = document.getElementById("toJavaScript").textContent;
```

I only get the default value `"DefaultPath"`. So do you have an idea how could I get the value after upload? Thank you for reading.

(also, the picture is shown only after uploading click and if I do one other refresh, `@myPath` is lost...)

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML page to see what value is stored in the `div`?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, you want to upload your picture on button click, Once it is uploaded you want to show it on UI, as well as you want to store the path in database?

Comment: this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.webimage.write?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#System_Web_Helpers_WebImage_Write_System_String_ may help you.

Comment: Yes @Sachin Vishwakarma, it seems to be simple but the value is lost after refresh (because i'm setting it on default value in razor when refreshing the page I think)

Comment: That is going to happen, HTTP is stateless. What i can suggest you here is that expand your code and when it is not post (your if conditon) then try to read the image, it might return you the last uploaded image's path. I am sure its very simple to try.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'm trying this.

Comment: Sorry I edited my message because to see the picture well, it needs to be myPath in the src, not imagePath.

So yes, @Peter Smith the value shown in the div is /Images/68e00fa8-b158-48f2-bdcc-9ba0ec7bc879_4L.jpg after upload And if i refresh, the value is DefaultPath again

Comment: @Sachin Vishwakarma I don't how to do it because the variable needs to be initialized and every time i'm refreshing, the initialisation needs to be done otherwise I can't use it inside JavaScript (or inside a div).

Comment: Ok, thank you everybody, I found a solution here:
https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/learn-to-upload-a-file-in-mvc-via-ajax/

Using Ajax and an ActionResult inside the Controller. Then inside the view, I'm using a dictionary to get the image path from the database. So I'm not using razor but the submit button, correlated to an ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

> But my goal is to get the variable @myPath into JavaScript

You can get the razor variable value in javascript variable like this:

```
<script>
     var myPath = "@myPath.ToString()";
</script>
```